# Can I update my web app even after receiving facebook approval

Tags: facebook

I have created a facebook app which works as a website. My users can make a post to their timelines using this app. I am submitting for app approval. I have a doubt that after receiving approval from Facebook, can I still make changes in my web app. There can be bugs for e.g.

Comment: Yes you can make changes after it is approved

Comment: You can register the callback handler, as https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/Spring-Social/blob/master/src/main/java/com/test/controller/FacebookController.java

Comment: @Arpit: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Piece of code has two callbacks, one for error and one for success, so I attached source so one can refer this to register the callback, and perform changes to your app once you are back to your app after approval from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can make these changes after the approval.  I make them constantly with my Facebook apps.